# Running Selenium Webdriver on Xvfb - firefox error

Tags: php, firefox, selenium, xvfb

I'm trying to run some automated Selenium tests on a server at work running on centros with firefox 10.0.12 installed as follows:

```
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 800x600x16&
export DISPLAY=:99;
java -jar ./autotesting/selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar&
php ./autotesting/index.php;
```

index.php points to a SimpleTest test class that starts up a WebDriver session like this (using the facebook php bindings):

```
$webdriver = new WebDriver();
$this->session = $webdriver->session('firefox');
$this->session->open($this->url);
```

It runs on my local machine but on the server I get the following output:

```
13:17:11.344 INFO - Executing: [new session: {browserName=firefox}] at URL: /session)
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on       port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
mkdir: `99/.mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}': Not a directory

(Gecko:8766): libgnomevfs-WARNING **: Unable to create ~/.gnome2 directory: Not a directory
Could not create per-user gnome configuration directory `99/.gnome2/': Not a directory
mkdir: `99/.mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}': Not a directory
```

I don't know enough about what's going on behind the scenes to troubleshoot this - why is the mkdir command being executed when firefox runs? Is it failing because I'm not a root user?

Comment: Does the directory `~/.gnome2` exist on the server for the user running the script? It is needed for saving firefox configuration and temporary data.

Comment: looks like something's fishy about the envirenmont that firefox is trying to run in. Perhaps the HOME environmental variable is set to "99" instead of something sensible like "/home/something"